# Uploading images via the Orchid Laravel library

Tags: laravel, orchid

I'm trying to upload an image from storage and insert it into the table. I tried a bunch of options for forming a path to a photo and none of them worked. Below are examples of paths.I work through WSL.

```
TD::make('image', 'Картинка')->render(function (News $news){
            return "<img src="{asset($news->image)}"";
            return  asset($news->image);
        }),
```

[image][image]

Answer (score 2):

I already read the Orchid documentation and it seems that you should use some built-in function for uploading files including images.
This is an example from Orchid website:

```
use Orchid\Attachment\File;

public function upload(Request $request)
{
    $path = "photos"
    $image= new File($request->file('photo'));
    $attachment = $image->path($path)->load();

    return response()->json()
}
```

If you want to access your uploaded image then try this:

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/photos/'.$image) }}" alt="{{ $image}}" class="some class">
```

Comment: Hello, I am trying to output or at least access the downloaded file. It is saved as usual in storage (I executed the storage:link command). Then going along the route https://localhost/storage/2023/09/07/6cc3be1117b25121d1e58536494b6a6287fbb58e.png I get the response {"status":false,"message":"Object not found"}. I've already tried a bunch of different routes and none of them brought up my file.

Comment: You can access your images as mentioned (Edited answer) in the my answer or you can use Github Intervention package for optimizing and uploading your images to your Laravel storage. You can create or update your news with images inserting image filename or path/filename into the DB and reach it everywhere.

Comment: That's the problem, I enter the correct path to the picture, but I don't get anything